# Execute a linux shell command with "sudo" using java, without entering the required password

Tags: java, passwords, cmd, sudo

Hi I'm using ganymed-ssh2 java library to execute remote commands in linux workstation with success.

But now there is a situation where I need to execute a command but this require that i put some password...like:

```
sudo /usr/bin/some_process
please enter your password:
```

I used to implement remote cmd execution in this way:

```
Session sess = conn.openSession();

sess.execCommand("uname -a && date && uptime && who");

System.out.println("Here is some information about the remote host:");

InputStream stdout = new StreamGobbler(sess.getStdout());

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));

while (true)
{
  String line = br.readLine();
  if (line == null)
  break;
  System.out.println(line);
}


System.out.println("ExitCode: " + sess.getExitStatus());

sess.close();

conn.close();
```

I'm afraid that it's not possible to execute commands that require a password with this library.

Someone could give me a solution or alternative to allow this ???

Thx!

Comment: The title of this post is a little misleading – it sounds like you're having password problems with ssh, but you're actually having password problems inside the ssh session. Consider adding something like 'remote sudo password entry' in the topic and/or tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming there is a `sess.getStdin()`, you should be able to pipe in a password to the sudo command.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to give the user that Java program logs in as the ability to run that sudo command without entering the password. You can do that by running visudo on the host and entering NOPASSWD after the given command. See `man 8 visudo` for more details.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The easiest thing to do is probably to use [public key authentication](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/532.cfm). That way you don't need a password.</strike>

**Edit:** I was mislead that this question was about SSH, when in fact it's about sudo. In that case kojiro's solution is the correct one: edit the `/etc/sudoers` file, use the `NOPASSWD` flag.