# How to run sudo command without password from java program?

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Execute a linux shell command with “sudo” using java, without entering the required password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168755/execute-a-linux-shell-command-with-sudo-using-java-without-entering-the-requi)

I want to execute sudo command on linux through java program but it ask for password.
But I want to run prog without password,please tell me.
My prog is

```
public class JavaCommandProg {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String command="sudo cat /etc/sudoers";
        Process myProcess =null;
        try {
            Runtime runtime=Runtime.getRuntime();
            File file=new File("/home/users/admin/temp");
            myProcess = runtime.exec(command,null,file);
            myProcess.waitFor();
            InputStreamReader myIStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(myProcess.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(myIStreamReader);
            String line;
            while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException anIOException) {
            System.out.println(anIOException);
        }
    }
}

Compling like: javac JavaCommandProg.java
and          : java JavaCommandProg
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168755/execute-a-linux-shell-command-with-sudo-using-java-without-entering-the-requi

Answer (score 1):

Grant your user the permissions by using sudo. Have a look here: http://www.ducea.com/2006/06/18/linux-tips-password-usage-in-sudo-passwd-nopasswd/

For example:

```
/etc/sudoers
admin    ALL = NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can get it to run that would mean a security flaw.

Said so...

1. Grant your user permissions (become sudoer)
2. Invoke your java program with sudo

   $ sudo java JavaCommandProg

This will prompt you for introducing sudo password when running jvm and then you can invoke sudo from inside your Java program.

Comment: thanks,now my program running

Comment: I'm glad you find it useful! BUT, watch out what you do inside your java program since you are sudoer (for good and for bad).