# Java working with linux sudo abilities

Tags: java, linux, passwords, command, root

I would like to know if there is any way for Java to prompt the user for the administrative password, like what they would use with sudo, so that I can run commands in the Java program without having to do weird stuff with the system or Sudoers. I have seen in done in Python, ie with the program gufw, and I would like to be able to do it with Java.

Comment: duplicate?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168755/execute-a-linux-shell-command-with-sudo-using-java-without-entering-the-requi

Answer (score 0):

To act as gufw you must use [polkit](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/latest/polkit.8.html) along with [dbus-java](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-java/). Another possibly simpler solution is to build a command (e.g. "sudo command" and run it with Runtime.getRuntime().exec
Doing this can be very dangerous must be done carefully.